# Python algorithm to find the full names in a text

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to put a simple algorithm to return first name and last name from a list containing a mix of first name and last names. For instance from the list

```
l = ['John May', ' May', 'John', 'John Smith','Jack', 'John','May Smith', 'Sandra', 'Tim John','Simon, 'Tim Sandra', 'Sandra Smith']
```

I would like to do the following:

1. If there is a single first name or last name in the text return only the full name containing that single first name or last name
2. If there is no full name return that single first name and last name

I wrote the following code to achieve that but I have only tested on a few test cases. I was wondering if someone can tell how to make this code more efficient and notice any issues with it.

```
l = ['John May', ' May', 'John', 'John Smith', 'John','May Smith', 'Sandra', 'Tim John', 'Tim Sandra', 'Sandra Smith', 'Simon', 'jack']

def get_unique_full_name(l):
    t = list(set(l))
    print(t)
    person = []
    for i in range(0,len(t)):
        for j in range(0,len(t)):
            if t[i] in t[j].split() or t[j] in t[i].split():
                if (t[i] != t[j]):
                    temp = t[i] if len(t[i]) == max(len(t[i]),len(t[j])) else t[j]
                    person.append(temp)
print(get_unique_full_name(l))
```

returns:(Expected output)

```
['John', 'May Smith', ' May', 'Sandra', 'Tim Sandra', 'John May', 'Sandra Smith', 'Simon', 'Tim John', 'jack', 'John Smith']
```

Comment: the expected output is already there in the body of my question ( under return).

Comment: Not able to understand your question.

Comment: Do you want to sort dictionary with specific logic?